# How to access nested modules/files from nested directories

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Let's say that I have this file structure in my project:

```sh
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── src
│   ├── hotel
│   │   ├── guest.rs
│   │   ├── hotel_manager.rs
│   │   └── hotel.rs
│   ├── lib.rs
│   └── main.rs
```

In `hotel_menager` I declared only that I will use `hotel` and `guest` module:

```rust
pub mod hotel;
pub mod guest;
```

Then inside `lib.rs` I declared that I will use `hotel_manager` module:

```rust
pub mod hotel_manager;
```

and in the end I wanted to use `hotel` and `guest` in my `main.rs` ***binary*** but I am getting this error :

> file not found for module `hotel_manager`

Then I thought that maybe I should use `use` but it also didn't help at all:

```rust
use crate::hotel::hotel_manager;
```

> unresolved import `crate::hotel`.

My `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "learn_file_spliting"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["kaczor6418 <test@test.com>"]
edition = "2018"

[lib]
name = "lib"
path = "src/lib.rs"

[[bin]]
name = "main"
path = "src/main.rs"
```

How can I use this nested module in `lib.rs` and then use re-exported modules inside `main.rs` ?

I know that if I create `hotel_manager` in `/src` directory then everything will work, but I want to have this `hotel_manager` module inside nested directory and learn how to use nested modules.

Comment: `mod hotel_manager;` will look for `./hotel_manager.rs` or `./hotel_manager/mod.rs`, but not for `./hotel/hotel_manager.rs`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Rust, you can't create a module by simply having it exist in the directory tree. You have to explicitly declare it with `mod module_name;` statement. This doesn't only declare that a module named `module_name` is *used*, it declares that such a module *exists at all*.

`pub mod hotel_manager;` doesn't work in `src/lib.rs` because this tries to creates a submodule named `hotel_manager` in the crate's root module, which would have to exist in either `src/hotel_manager.rs` or `src/hotel_manager/mod.rs` -- and neither exist.

Importing `crate::hotel::hotel_manager` in `src/lib.rs` doesn't work because you have never declared a `pub mod hotel;` in `src/lib.rs`, and therefore, no module named `crate::hotel` exists at this point.

Basically, for the `hotel_manager` module to exist at `src/hotel/hotel_manager.rs`, it would have to be declared as a submodule of the a `crate::hotel` module, which itself would need to be declared in the root module.

The way to do what you want is to write the following in `src/lib.rs`:

```rust
pub mod hotel;
```

This submodule named `hotel` would have to exist at either `src/hotel.rs` or `src/hotel/mod.rs`. Since we want it to have further submodules, by convention, the latter is used. So create a file named `src/hotel/mod.rs`, with the following contents:

```rust
pub mod guest;
pub mod hotel_manager;
pub mod hotel;
```

This creates a proper module structure we want with `hotel` as a submodule of the root module, which contains further submodules named `guest`, `hotel_manager` and `hotel`.

Then, in the `crate::hotel::hotel_manager` module, instead of using `mod` statements, you should use the following statements, which import the modules that have been declared elsewhere into the current scope:

```rust
use crate::hotel::guest;
use crate::hotel::hotel;
```

Note that in Rust, you can import items smaller than just the whole module. For example, if you have a struct named `Hotel` in the `crate::hotel::hotel` module, you can import only that with a statement like `use crate::hotel::hotel::Hotel;`